# ACF filter to exclude all categories from select

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I am using "Frontend Submit Pro" and "ACF(not pro) plugins for WordPress.
I am using these plugins to make frontend post creator for my users.

I have more than 200+ categories so I want to make it more easy for my users to select categories. I will create multiple forms and each form will have a few categories to be selected from users.

For now i use the below filter to exclude some categories from forms.

```
add_filter('acf/fields/taxonomy/query/name=kathgories', 'exclude_categories', 10, 2);

function exclude_categories( $args, $field ) {
    global $uncategorized_id;
    $args['exclude'] = array(290,287,283,289,281,291,286,280,284,279); //the IDs of the excluded terms
    return $args;
}
```

Because I have a lot of categories I can't exclude 200 categories in the above code is too hard.

So i want a filter that will exclude all categories and include only the 5-10 categories that i want to be show in each form.
I have not the knowledge to do that so i am asking if anyone can help.

I also want each filter apply to only one form. I need some way to link filters to the correct form.(maybe by link or form name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question.

I changed the "exclude" to "include" in the filter above and it seems to do exactly what I wanted.

It only shows the categories that I give it in the form.

For those who display categories within "select" use the following code.

```
add_filter('acf/fields/taxonomy/query/name=kathgories', 'include_categories', 10, 2);

function include_categories( $args, $field ) {
      global $uncategorized_id;
      $args['include'] = array(290,287,283,289,281,291,286,280,284,279); //the IDs of the excluded terms
      return $args;
}
```

For those who display categories in a "checkbox" use the following code.

```
add_filter('acf/fields/taxonomy/wp_list_categories/name=kathgories', 'my_taxonomy_args', 10, 2);

function my_taxonomy_args( $args, $field ){
      $args['include'] = array(197,247,245,250,246,248,249,251);//the IDs of the excluded terms
      return $args;
}
```

Also change `/name=kathgories'`
with your own ACF Taxonomy field name.

So with that change , I am answering my second question.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it with a filter.**

```
add_action( 'init', 'get_term_ids' );
function get_term_ids() {
    global $uncategorized_id;
    $u = get_term_by( 'slug', 'uncategorized', 'product_cat' );
    $uncategorized_id = $u->term_id;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/taxonomy/query/name=kathgories', 'exclude_categories', 10, 2);
function exclude_categories( $args, $field ) {
  global $uncategorized_id;
  $args['exclude'] = array($uncategorized_id); //the IDs of the excluded terms
  return $args;
}
```

Comment: This filter has the same functionality like the one that i posted.I want all categories be excluded by default and include only a few. The opposite of above filter.

Comment: Please i will change code Go ahead with this Code and give me your thoughts.

Comment: I think your code only exclude all categories and not see a way to include after the categories that i want. I tried your code and is not working for me. Is not exclude any category from form.